# How to get woocommerce product categories as drop down list in a form field? I am using captain form plugin for building customized form

Tags: wordpress, forms, woocommerce

[form-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAXFn.png)

Look at this picture. I have a dropdown list for the product category which is hardcoded. But I want to load category list dynamically from woocommerce.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check here to how ask question https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Well talke this answer as a reference it will help a bit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009516/get-woocommerce-product-categories-from-wordpress

Comment: Thank you. I hope it's gonna help.